# Increment number after method is called Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have simple class with void method.

```
public class Simple {
     public Void doSomething() {}
}
```

And I want to increment a number in my test after calling `doSomething()`.

```
@Test
public void test1() {
     int number = 0;
     Simple simple = Mockito.mock(Simple.class);
     Mockito.when(simple.doSomething()).then(number++);
}
```

Of course it is causing compilation error. How can I increment `number` after calling `doSomething()` ?

**Alternative solution:**

It's very bad practice but it's alternative solution for best answer below.

```
private int number = 0;

@Test
public void test1() {
     Simple simple = Mockito.mock(Simple.class);
     Mockito.when(simple.doSomething()).thenReturn(increment());
}

private Void increment() {
     number++;
     return null;
}
```

Comment: I know that I can verify how many times the method was called in Mockito, but I want to exactly increment number after method is called.

Comment: I have exactly task which I wrote. That's why I asked is it possible.

Comment: What is your end goal? What do you want to do with `number`?

Comment: You can make a trick. In your test, extend Simple class by SimpleMock and override `doSomething()`. Also, add static attribute which increment each time you call `doSomething()`. Now, via mockito, `spy` SimpleMock class and you will get incremented value. [http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html)

Comment: @Valijon I was afraid that is the only way. I was wondering if there is in Mockito way to call method after mocked method is called, but unfortunately it's propably impossible. Because I could create number static and calling method incrementNumber.

Comment: Please don't write your "Alternative solution" into the question. Post an answer for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not clear from your question why you would want to have such a thing. The code in this answer is not good practice and I won't recommend it.

---

The first problem is that your method returns `void` so you can't stub it with `Mockito.when`. [You need to use `Mockito.doWhen`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12).

In this code, I use `Mockito.doAnswer` to write a custom code inside the answer part:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
     int[] number = { 0 };
     Simple simple = Mockito.mock(Simple.class);
     Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            number[0]++;
            return null;
        }
    }).when(simple).doSomething();
}
```

The trick is to store the number inside a final variable (in this case, an array) and increment its only value in the answer part. Each time `doSomething()` will be called, it will be incremented and you will have the count inside `number[0]`.

The same code can be made more compact with Java 8:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> number[0]++).when(simple).doSomething();
```

Comment: can you provide links to more examples of the Java 8 syntax?

Comment: beautiful! Thank you